# Associations: one to many with existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails beginner here:

I already have a database and table, so the naming convention is giving me some headaches

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :categorie, :foreign_key => "catid"   
end

class Categorie < ActiveRecord ...    
  has_many :item
end
```

---

```
i = Item.first    # Ok

c = i.Categorie   # Ok,  finds proper Categorie based on "catid" of i

c.Item # fails with Categorie_id column not found ! how can i map Categorie_id to "catid"?
```

Comment: For `has_many` relation,you should be using plural form.Change it to `has_many :items` and try `c.items`

Comment: thx Pavan and Kirti, see the answer and my comments below

Answer (score 1):

You're a rails beginner but you might not be a programmer beginner so I'll dive in and explain classes a little bit.

[A class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html) is simply a data object that holds methods. Nothing more. Here's a simple one that holds one method:

```
class Cow
    def talk
        "moo"
    end
end
```

`Cow` is the class, `talk` is the method. Now, if we have the above classes in memory, we cannot do this in the console:

```
talk
```

Because that method isn't available at the global scope. This is a good thing, because this could cause bugs and is inefficient. Imagine if we have a few animals:

```
class Cat
    def talk
        "meow"
    end
end

class Dog
    def talk
        "woof"
    end
end
```

Running `talk`, how would the computer know which `talk` to run? Instead, we call the method that's inside the class like this:

```
Cow.talk #=> "moo"
Cat.talk #=> "meow"
Dog.talk #=> "woof"
```

Hopefully now, this code:

```
Item.first
```

is less cryptic. `Item` is a class, and `first` is a method available inside that class.

Now I know `Item` is a model, but in rails, **models are simply classes that inherit a bunch of useful methods from ActiveRecord**. At the top of the `Item` model you should see this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
```

That's what pulls in all of the useful methods, such as the `first` method we're using. Because of this inheritance, we can *imagine* your Item class looks a bit like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    def first
       # code is in here that queries the table in your database that has
       # the downcased and pluralized name of Item (so items) and returns the first
       # row of that table
    end 

    # down here is all of your methods you've probably created. Validations and the like.
end
```

`first`, rather than return a string like in my example does something far more useful; it queries the table in your database that has the downcased and pluralized name of its class. So `Item.first` queries the `items` table, and returns the first row.

Now, I have to be honest, despite what you say, I find it highly doubtful that `i.Categorie` finds the proper Categorie based on the "catid" of i. If it truly does I feel you've done some crazy workaround to get that working. This is what should happen:

```
i.Categorie
NoMethodError: undefined method `Categorie' for #<Item:0x00000005905830>
```

In plain English, this means

```
NoMethodError: there is no 'Categorie' method inside that instance of the 'Item' class.
```

And this makes sense because I see no 'Categorie' method in here:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    def first
       # code is in here that queries the table in your database that has
       # the downcased and pluralized name of Item (so items) and returns the first
       # row of that table
    end 

    # down here is all of your methods you've probably created. Validations and the like.
end
```

Now the reason `c.Item` doesn't work is because `c` is set to `nil` because `nil` was returned by `i.Categorie` due to the non-method error, and `nil` certainly doesn't have the method `Item` inside it.

```
c = i.Categorie # c is set to nil due to noMethodError
c.Item
NoMethodError: undefined method `Item' for nil:NilClass
```

Hopefully you understand a bit more what's going on now. If you want your code to work you should be doing this. Look closely, there are a few nuances:

```
i = Item.first    # i is set to the first instance of Item
c = i.categorie   # c is set to the instance of Categorie that i belongs to
is = c.items      # returns an array consisting of all the Item instances that belong to the Categorie instance in c
```

We could also do this:

```
is.first # returns i
```

So where do all these handy methods come from? The `categorie` method inside `i` (`i.category`), the `items` method inside `c` (`c.items`)? The answer is they're created dynamically by Rails based on your inheritance and pulled into the relevant model by < ActiveRecord::Base.

By "based on your inheritance" I mean, how you've used the inheritance methods, `belongs_to` and `has_many`:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :categorie, :foreign_key => "catid" # creates categorie method that returns the instance of Categorie this instance of Item belongs to    
end

class Categorie < ActiveRecord ...    
  has_many :item # creates items method that returns an array of all the instances of Item that belong to this instance of Categorie  
end
```

I would also point out that Categorie is a pretty terrible Model name, purely because it's spelt wrongly. Maybe `Type` would be better?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Ah thanks, I thought I was banging on a bit much x)

Comment: c.Items
  Item Load (14.5ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`  WHERE `items`.`categorie_id` = 20
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'items.categorie_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`  WHERE `items`.`categorie_id` = 20
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'items.categorie_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`  WHERE `items`.`categorie_id` = 20
and it is true, categorie_id does not exist, it's catid that exists. I can simply rename the column, from catid to categorie_id, but that's not the point

Comment: i = Item.first
  Item Load (13.2ms)  SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items`   ORDER BY `items`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Item id: 73, title: "despre centrala de la ...", alias: "ram-man-1", **catid: 20**, published: 0, introtext: "<p> </p>\r\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\">\r\n<object...", fulltext: "...", video: nil, gallery: nil, created: "2010-05-26 16:58:29", created_by: 62, created_by_alias: "", image_caption: "", image_credits: "", video_caption: "", video_credits: "", hits: 96>
_as i said, the database was preexisting_

Comment: c = i.Categorie
  Categorie Load (12.6ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories`  WHERE **`categories`.`id` = 20** LIMIT 1
=> #<Categorie id: 20, name: "Intervenții în plen", alias: "intervenții-în-plen", parent: 18, published: 1, ordering: 1>

Comment: of course Categorie is a terrible model becaus the database was preexisting so i had to name the model categorie to get the 'categories' table :)

Comment: so my problem is to map a model to existing database tables. The association is one ( Categorie ) to many ( Items ). As u can see it finds the first item. Then I use this first item's 'Categorie' method to find the corresponding 'Categorie' ( and I have declared 'catid' as the foreign key ). It seems it's working, u can see the highlighted 'catid' and 'categories.id' = 20 ). However, when I want to get all items that belong to that 'Categorie' the SQL is generated with 'categorie_id' instead 'catid'. I thought rails by then knows what the foreign key in this one-to-many is ( declared 'catid' )

Comment: The Rails mantra is convention over configuration. It's conventional to have the foreign key called 'categorie_id', not 'catid', just so you know.

Comment: ok, but since there's such thing as :foreign_key => "", it would work properly. I will rename the column, thanks

Comment: @user272900 I'd delete that `:foreign_key =>`, it's not needed thanks to the rails defaults, and so may be causing trouble. Just remember the column that holds the foreign keys has to be called `categorie_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
Item.create (:catid => @categorie.id)

@categorie = Categorie.find(params[:id]) or with Categorie.all 
place the each loop & find the id .

Answer (score 0):

First you should have used **Category** for model because rails intelligently understands the plural categories or tables.

Secondly, you should have something like this;

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :Category, :foreign_key => "catid"   
end

class Categorie < ActiveRecord ...    
  has_many :items
end

i = Item.first



c = i.Category



c.items #to find all items that belong to the category c
```